# Getting the following error

Tags: errors, missing

What I type is:

```
 \item Prove that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} 7^{{-4x}^2} dx = \frac {\sqrt \pi}{4 \sqrt \log 7}$.
```

The error I am getting is:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \mathop 
l.71 ...^2} dx = \frac {\sqrt \pi}{4 \sqrt \log 7}
                                                  $.
?
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are missing the brackets around the argument for what is supposed to be under the square root. Try this:

```
$ \int_{0}^{\infty} 7^{{-4x}^2} dx = \frac {\sqrt{ \pi}}{4 \sqrt {\log 7}}$
```

And it should translate correctly.